# The spacing issue comes when using the side drawer and scroll view in native script angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing android and ios applications using native script-angular. I am using UISidedrawer plugin for showing the menu's, I have an issue while using  UISidedrawer and ScrollView same time, In my component, space was automatically taken. Here are my code and screenshot.

I am creating a side drawer and menu's like:

```
<RadSideDrawer [transition]="drawerTransition">
    <GridLayout rows="auto,*,110" column="auto" tkDrawerContent height="100%">

            <StackLayout row="0" column="0" orientation="vertical" class="sidedrawer-header">
                    <Label class="italic" text="Welcome "></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <ListView row="1" column="0" [items] = "navMenu" rowHeight="40"   class="sidedrawer-content" separatorColor="#40053e" (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)">
                <ng-template>
                    <StackLayout 
            //code
                    </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </ListView> 

            <StackLayout row="2" column="0" class="sidedrawer-footer" orientation="vertical">
                    <Button text="Logout"  (tap)="logout()" pageTransition="slideright"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout> 

    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <StackLayout>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout> 
</RadSideDrawer>
```

**My side drawer component.ts code**

```
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular';
import { SlideInOnTopTransition } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "side-drawer",
    templateUrl: 'side-drawer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['side-drawer.component.css']
})

export class SideDrawerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {
    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;

    private drawer: SideDrawerType;
    drawerTransition: any;



    navMenu: any[] = [
        {id: '0', name: 'Dashboard', icon: '~/Images/dashboard.png', commands: ['/dashboard'] },
        {id: '1', name: 'Status', icon: '~/Images/progress.png', commands: ['/status'] },
        {id: '2', name: 'Transcript', icon: '~/Images/send.png', commands: ['/transcript'] },
        {id: '3', name: 'Change Password', icon: '~/Images/password.png', commands: ['/password'] },
        {id: '4', name: 'Support', icon: '~/Images/contact.png', commands: ['/contact'] },
        {id: '5', name: 'About Us', icon: '~/Images/about.png', commands: ['/about'] },
        {id: '6', name: 'FAQ', icon:'~/Images/faq.png',commands:['/faq']},
    ];
  constructor( ) {
    this.drawerTransition = new SlideInOnTopTransition();
  }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
    }

}
```

**My menu content html**

```
<side-drawer>
        <GridLayout rows="*,100">
                <StackLayout row="0" orientation="vertical">
                        <StackLayout  orienatation="vertical">
                                <ScrollView>
                              <Label text="Hello World> </Label>
                </ScrollView>
                        </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout row="1">
                </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
</side-drawer>
```

[image]

How to remove unwanted space. Only the space issue occurs when we use a scroll view inside the side drawer and ios platform only.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to wrap ScrollView with so many StackLayouts. Try setting vertical alignment to top on ScrollView, if issue still persists please share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Ok manoj i will try.

Comment: No manoj it's not worked.Can you tell me how to share a playground sample? I dont know about that.

Comment: Checkout https://play.nativescript.org/ / https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-playground-is-on-fire